# How much data required in the 747 design?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am interest in how much computer data is required in building the 747>

Comment: What? I assume you're asking about the amount of research used to design the 747 in the first place. We definitely can't provide a clear answer to that. It's reasonable to say that, directly or indirectly, the majority of all aviation literature would have been read by at least one of the designers on the team.

Comment: What sort of answer were you looking for? "57.3 TB"?

Answer (score 5):

The 747 was designed in the 1960s (rollout in September 1968) so a rather simplistic answer to "how much computer data..." is none. The design would have been done on manual drafting tables using slide rules and mechanical calculators, with actual computers only used for the occasional complex calculation assuming they didn't crash in the process. These calculations would have produced a single value or small set of values, not a finished design by modern standards

You are possibly thinking of the 777 design process. This was the first Boeing product designed entirely with CAD systems. They use CATIA by Dassault, the details are not readily available but I think we can assume that the amount of data involved is Large.